# Checking the type of an element in an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, types, element

Just started with Javascript and am trying to check the type of an element in an `array`: I have a `function` that takes two functions as `parameters`. I have an `array` which has a combination of `string` and `number` elements. The idea is to trigger `functions` based on the type of element in the sample `array` and then push a new `element` to a new `array`. I'm not sure which bulit in function i can use here. I tried `indexOf` and `typeof` but these don't seem to serve the purpose or maybe I'm doing this wrong. Below is the code. Thanks a lot!

```
var arr1 = [3, "Hello", 5, "Hola"];

function setNewArray(arr, funct1, funct2){
    var arr2 = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(/*check if arr[i] is a string*/){
            arr2.push(funct1(arr[i]));
        }

        if(/*check if arr[i] is a number*/){
            arr2.push(funct2(arr[i]));
        }       
    }
    return arr2;
}


var numfunct = function(item){
    return item * 2;
}


var strfunct = function(item){
    return item + " " + "there";
}

var result = setNewArray(arr1, numfunct, strfunct);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Yes [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) is what you need, how did you used it?

Comment: Have a look at the documentation of [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof), [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) and parseInt.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it easily using `typeof` like following

For the first code block

```
if(typeof arr[i] === 'string'){
     arr2.push(   
     funct1(arr[i]));
}
```

For the second one

```
if(typeof arr[i] === 'number'){
      arr2.push(
      funct2(arr[i]));
    }
```

Comment: @Ben If you think this one solves your problem please mark it as an answer.

Comment: Your code does not solve the problem because there is another problem with OP's code, they are passing the function for the number as `func1` (same thing for the string function), and this is why I believe your question was not accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

```js
var arr1 = [3, "Hello", 5, "Hola" ];

function setNewArray(arr, funct1, funct2){

    var arr2 = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){

        if(!isNaN(arr[i])){ // or use this alternative typeof arr[i]  == 'number'
         arr2.push(   
            funct1(arr[i]));
        }


        if(typeof (arr[i]) == 'string'){

          arr2.push(

              funct2(arr[i]));
        }       


    }
    return arr2;
    }


var numfunct = function(item){

    return item * 2;

}


var strfunct = function(item){

    return item + " " + "there";
}

var result = setNewArray(arr1, numfunct, strfunct);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Why not just `typeof arr[i] === "number"` ? `isNaN` seems to provide only one advantage in this case, and that in an extremely unlikely case.

Comment: @Taurus I edited my answer. I just wanted to use an alternative.

Comment: I recommend editing it back then, that alternative was a bit different than the other solutions here, with this edit, your answer looks like a 1-to-1 clone of every other answer to this question.

Comment: @Taurus how about both? :-)

Comment: Nice but almost invisible :)

Answer (score 1):

Create an object of functions, where each function name is the type it can handle. Iterate the array with [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and select the right method from the object using [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).

Note: I've added a boolean handler to convert the `true` to yes.

```js
var arr1 = [3, "Hello", 5, "Hola", true];

var fns = {
  number(item) {
      return item * 2;
  },
  
  string(item) {
    return item + " " + "there";
  },
  
  boolean(item) {
    return item ? 'yes' : 'no'
  }
};

function setNewArray(arr, fns) {
  return arr.map(function(item) {
    return fns[typeof item](item);
  });
}

var result = setNewArray(arr1, fns);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: All this is just unnecessary and needlessly smart.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `typeof` to check the type of any variable or object. And you do not need to pass the function refrence. Here is the code:

```
var arr1 = [3, "Hello", 5, "Hola"];

function setNewArray(arr) {
  var arr2 = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    if (typeof arr[i] === 'string') {
      arr2.push(
        strfunct(arr[i]));
    }

    if (typeof arr[i] === 'number') {
      arr2.push(
        numfunct(arr[i]));
    }
  }
  return arr2;
}

var numfunct = function (item) {
  return item * 2;
}

var strfunct = function (item) {
  return item + " " + "there";
}

var result = setNewArray(arr1);
console.log(result);
```

[image: Here is the output]

Comment: Passing the functions as parameters makes the code more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [typeof](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/typeof-operator-decrementjavascript) Operator in javascript

```js
var arr1 = [3, "Hello", 5, "Hola"];

function setNewArray(arr, funct1, funct2) {
    var arr2 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (typeof arr[i] == 'string') {
            arr2.push(funct1(arr[i]));
        }
        if (typeof arr[i] == 'number') {
            arr2.push(funct2(arr[i]));
        }
    }
    return arr2;
}


var numfunct = function (item) {
    return item * 2;
}


var strfunct = function (item) {
    return item + " " + "there";
}

var result = setNewArray(arr1, strfunct, numfunct);
console.log(result);
```

I think this is the exact function that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not with the use of typeof operator but with the function called with number and string.

Updated code:

```
var arr1 = [3, "Hello", 5, "Hola" ];

function setNewArray(arr, funct1, funct2){

    var arr2 = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){

        if(typeof arr[i] == "string"){
         arr2.push(   
            funct2(arr[i]));
        }


        if(typeof arr[i] == "number"){

          arr2.push(

              funct1(arr[i]));
        }       


    }
    return arr2;
    }


var numfunct = function(item){

    return item * 2;

}


var strfunct = function(item){

    return item + " " + "there";
}

var result = setNewArray(arr1, numfunct, strfunct);
console.log(result);
```